# MySQL - Insert row into table 2 for each updated row in table 1

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a `table_1` that looks like this:

```
serial  myBool   dateTime
------  ------   --------
1       0        2016-05-03 10:23:45
2       1        2016-05-03 09:13:21
3       0        2016-05-03 08:44:33
```

A MySQL scheduled event runs periodically and if the dateTime is old enough, it sets `myBool` to 0. So far so good.
Each time `myBool` is set to 0, I wish to add a new row to `table_2` as follows:

```
table_1_serial   dateTime
--------------   --------
2                2016-05-03 09:13:21
```

I created a trigger thus:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `myTrigger` AFTER UPDATE ON `table_1`
FOR EACH ROW 
    IF myBool = 0 THEN INSERT INTO `table_2` VALUES(`serial`, `dateTime`); 
END IF
```

However now when I modify a `table_1` row, I get this message:

```
Unknown column 'myBool' in 'field list'
```

I'd appreciate any help getting the trigger working, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `new.` for the column reference:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `myTrigger` AFTER UPDATE ON `table_1`
FOR EACH ROW 
    IF new.myBool = 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO `table_2`
            VALUES(new.`serial`, new.`dateTime`); 
    END IF;
```